# How do you express having a mutual acquaintance when you introduce yourself?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

Let's imagine that Jack told me about his friend who is a lawyer, called Mark.

And that Jack also told me that I have to mention to Mark that I know him (Jack).

How can I introduce myself to Mark and get this information across?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hi Mark, I'm Bob. I'm a friend of Jack Smith's."

or

"Hi Mark, my name is Bob Jones. Jack Smith recommended you to me."

Answer (score 1):

You must be Mark. By the way I think we have a friend in common Jack FamilyName (Our friend Jack has really recommend you as a lawyer).